# Add a event to full calendar from custom list

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, custom-lists

I have a hard time to understand how the full calendar plug in works if you want to add a new event. 
Every example i have seen is hard coded events, not from textboxes. 
I have a custom list where i can add new courses (making a course catalog), what i want with my calendar is that the events that is in the custom list will be showing in the calendar to, after the right date (from a textbox).

Does anyone know how to connect a custom list to a fullcalendar? So when a new event is added in the custom list, it also will be added into the full calendar!

will be really glad if someone could give me an example.

Doing it with javascript!

var createinfo = SP.ListCreationInformation();

```
var newtask = list.addItem(createinfo);
newtask.set_item('Kursnamn', $('#TextKursnamn').val());
newtask.set_item('Malgrupp', $('#TextMalgrupp').val());
newtask.set_item('Forkunskapskrav', $('#TextForkunskapskrav').val());
newtask.set_item('Matrielkrav', $('#TextMatriellkrav').val());
newtask.set_item('Omfattning', $('#SelectOmfattning').val());
newtask.set_item('Kursledare', $('#TextKursledare').val());
newtask.set_item('Telefonnr', $('#TextTelefonnummer').val());
newtask.set_item('Email', $('#TextEmail').val());
newtask.set_item('Startdatum', $('#TextStartdatum').val());
newtask.set_item('Slutdatum', $('#TextSlutdatum').val());
newtask.set_item('SistaAnmalninsgdag', $('#TextSistaanmalningsdag').val());
newtask.set_item('Fritext', $('#TextInformation').val());
newtask.update();

clientContext.load(newtask);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success_Createlist, onFail);
```

//And the calendar is just empty right now

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

});
```

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted

Comment: i have edit my question and added som code now